# How to get the firsts and lasts (variable) characters in a string with Python Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

We have this:

```
def get_prices():
    prices = pd.read_json("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices")
    prices_df = pd.DataFrame(prices)
    prices_df.columns = ["Price","Symbol"]
    prices_df = prices_df.set_index("Symbol") 
    prices_df["Asset"] = "??"
    prices_df["Quote"] = "??"
    return prices_df
```

The "Symbol" here is a pair composed of "Asset" + "Quote" symbol without any separation.
To make it a little more difficult, the "Asset" and "Quote" have different lengths.
Examples:LTCBTC,BNBUSDT,NEOBTC,QTUMETH
(you can check more samples by running the function)

But we know that the "Quote" symbols can only be 4:
"USDT","BTC","ETH","BNB"

So which code do we use to define each column ("Asset" and "Quote") in the dataframe?

Comment: `^(\w+)(USDT|BTC|ETH|BNB)$` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can see that it works here: https://i.imgur.com/7UpLMjV.png.
But I confused on how to define the columns in the function. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you may use is `^\w+(USDT|BTC|ETH|BNB)$` that matches a string that starts with 1 or more word chars (`\w+`) and ends with either of the `USDT`, `BTC`, `ETH` or `BNB` substrings. However, you need to adjust it for use with Pandas.

You may just use `str.extract`  to fill the columns with the right values by wrapping the corresponding pattern parts with capturing parentheses:

```
prices_df["Asset"] = prices_df["Symbol"].str.extract(r'^(\w+)(?:USDT|BTC|ETH|BNB)$', expand=False).fillna('')
prices_df["Quote"] = prices_df["Symbol"].str.extract(r'^\w+(USDT|BTC|ETH|BNB)$', expand=False).fillna('')
```

You may also use named capturing groups to `str.extract` the values and create the corresponding columns:

```
prices_df = prices_df.join(prices_df['Symbol'].str.extract(r'^(?P<Asset>\w+)(?P<Quote>USDT|BTC|ETH|BNB)$', expand=True))
```

Pandas demo code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol':['LTCBTC','BNBUSDT','NEOBTC','QTUMETH']})
df = df.join(df['Symbol'].str.extract(r'^(?P<Asset>\w+)(?P<Quote>USDT|BTC|ETH|BNB)$', expand=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Symbol Asset Quote
0   LTCBTC   LTC   BTC
1  BNBUSDT   BNB  USDT
2   NEOBTC   NEO   BTC
3  QTUMETH  QTUM   ETH
```